# Training data set and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation

I would like to have some clarification because I have the same doubt every time.

1. Training data is used to build the model,
2. Validation data is used with cross validation for hyper parameter tuning or model selection or feature selection
3. Test data check the performance of the model

I have the impression from the literature that it uses the training data with cross validation for hyper parameter tuning.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a separate validation set, as commonly seen in many works employing neural networks, it's just validation, not CV. When CV is present, your validation set is not constant any more. Typically, the dataset is divided into train and test sets, and afterwards, on the entire training set, one uses cross-validation for hyper-parameter tuning, dynamically changing the validation fold and training folds. So, training set and validation set in CV is a bit intertwined. Probably, that is the reason you *feel* the literature seems to be using training set for hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Probably you use this :Data will be split into 50 percent - 25 percent - 25 percent to create training, validation, and testing data. Models developed on training and hyperparameters are tuned on validation data and finally get evaluated against test data, when  you do not use CV right ? if I understood well from your answer.

Comment: that is the approach commonly used in neural nets for example, where CV can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it now .

Comment: You're welcome @RuddiRodriguezGarcia If you think the answer is ok, can you please accept and/or upvote it?